# Exporting gridview to excel with combo,checkbox type columns + winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, gridview, export

I want to export grid view data to excel file in windows forms application. I tried one solution but it fails to export **combo box** type column to excel. Excel file should have **combo box, check box** columns.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a "check box" or "combo box" cell types in Excel - only form controls which can be added to worksheets.
You can create those objects programatically, using the Excel COM automation.